# Upload Image Flutter Storage

Tags: flutter

i am use 'image_picker_web/image_picker_web.dart' in my app. Now when I choosed image, this image displayed, it's work. But when i try to save image in storage nothing happens.

```
Uint8List _image1;

Future getImg() async {
Uint8List tempImg = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(asUint8List: true);

if (tempImg != null) {
  setState(() {
    // debugPrint(tempImg.toString());
    _image1 = tempImg;
  });
}}
```

save in storage:

```
void uploadImg() async {
final StorageReference productImg =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('ProductImg');
var timekey = DateTime.now();
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
    productImg.child(timekey.toString() + 'jpg').putData(_image1);
var imageUrl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
url = imageUrl.toString();
print('Image Url' + url);}
```

button:

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
     uploadImg();
 }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What `url` prints on console?

Comment: prints nothing. But debugprint prints [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74,.........]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
final file = File.fromRawPath(uint8list);
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("users/some_id/ProductImg.jpg");
final task = ref.putFile(file, StorageMetadata(contentType: "image/png"));
final snapshot = await task.onComplete;
if (snapshot.error != null) throw snapshot.error;
final downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: sorry, its doesnt work. still prints nothing and nothing happens. I hope you have any way.

Comment: Instead of converting `uint8list` to `File`, can you directly capture `File` and perform rest of the code? I did it and it worked.

Comment: I am new in flutter, if it doesn't bother you, can you explain how to do it?

Comment: Anyone can guide me??

Comment: @AndreyKhan I haven't tried that plugin before, so I can't assist you much. If you want to upload a photo from phone, I can provide full solution.

Comment: Above you wrote  can you directly capture File and perform rest of the code? I did it and it worked. I dont understand what you mean by that directly capture `File`? Just explain this part.

Comment: @AndreyKhan If you already did it and it worked then what didn't you understand?

Comment: sorry I am not correctly explained, You wrote a comment  'can you directly capture File and perform rest of the code? I did it and it worked'  so I dont understand what you mean by that directly capture File?